# How can I split strings in an array and place them in a (new) 2 dimensional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have created an `array` that looks like this:

```
['this', 'is', 'it']
```

How can I convert this to a 2-dimensional `array` that looks like this:
`[['t','h','i','s'], ['i', 's'], ['i', 't']]`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map`:

```js
const input = ['this', 'is', 'it'] 
const output = input.map(c => c.split(""))
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Works perfect for me! Thanks :-)

Comment: @Christian Don't forget to mark the answer as correct. :)

Comment: It says I can't do that because I have less than 15 reputation... (I'm new here today!)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) as callback for mapping the array.

```js
var input = ['this', 'is', 'it'],
    output = input.map(Object.values);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `Array.from` since it's a bit more readable.

```
['this', 'is', 'it'].map(s => Array.from(s));
```